# XeLaTeX, small caps bfseries

Tags: xetex, fontspec, bold, shapes

I found that this MWE, compiled with `pdflatex` provide what I need:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\bfseries\scshape Bold Small Caps}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I also pointed out that the combination `\scshape` and `\bfseres` works only with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` option.
Now I would like to get the same result using `XeLaTeX` but of course I cannot use `fontenc` package. I do not know how to do with `fontspec`

thank you

Comment: Replace `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with `\usepackage{fontspec}` and use a font which has bold smallcaps, e.g. `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}`.

Comment: I tried as you said. The point is it cannot find `CMU Serif`, and that I would like to use the default font, which I like so much.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no bold smallcaps in Latin Modern Roman.

Comment: So why with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` those font were available? Is it impossible to have them using `XeLaTeX`?

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in pdfLaTeX selects the [`cm-super`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cm-super?lang=en) fonts.  Unfortunately, T1 encoded fonts have the wrong mapping to be used with XeLaTeX.  If in any way possible, you should use [CMU Serif](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cm-unicode) which is a slightly modified version of `cm-super` but with correct mapping.

Comment: I see, but how can use it? I have a full TeXLive install on Linux but I'm having problems with the name of the fonts. [I don't even konw how to use Latin Modern Roman](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344045/xelatex-and-fontspec), i can use it because it is the default font. Can you help me?

Comment: add `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}` and try your test file with lualatex, if that works you have the fonts so you then just need to help xetex find them, if it doesn't work you need the cm-unicode distribution (which can be installed via tlmgr)

Comment: With LuaLaTeX it works! How cna I help xelatex to find it?

Comment: @MaPo I'm just wondering about that (I know a couple of ways but neither seems as straightforward as I'd like:-) let me check....

Comment: @MaPo http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34112747#34112747

Comment: As he writes it has an issue...

Comment: @MaPo issue resolved I think:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Luatex (or rather the `luaotfload` Lua module) has its own font searching code which is naturally kpathsearch-aware and will find system fonts and fonts in texlive both by filename and by the internal font name such as `CMU Serif`.

xetex uses the system font cache (fc-cache on linux and cygwin, and I think comes with a local copy of fc-cache on windows) it can find system and texlive fonts by filename but can only find fonts by font name if they are known to the system (eg via fc-cache).

You could load CMU Serif by filename

```
\setmainfont{cmunrm.otf}
```

For some fonts that is no problem and a convenient way to load fonts but the disadvantage of loading by filename is that fontspec can then not automatically infer variants such as bold and small caps, these can be specified individually to fontspec but for a large collection like CMU that is a pain.

Easier is to make the fonts available to the system, so xetex can load them by name. For example on my windows/cygwin setup I can just drag copies to `c:/windows/fonts`, on a Mac you could install the fonts in  `/Library/Fonts`.

Or on systems using fc-cache you can tell `fc-cache` to look in the texlive directories. If you save a file that looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

as

```
/etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf
```

then run

```
sudo fc-cache -fsv
```

xetex will find the fonts.

The config file is a version of the file supplied in texlive as

```
/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf
```

but restricted to opentype (the original had two extra lines for truetype and type1)

After all those preliminaries

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
%\setmainfont{cmunrm.otf}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}


{\bfseries Bold }

{\scshape Small Caps}

{\bfseries\scshape Bold Small Caps}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

(Thanks to egreg for help with some of the details here)

Comment: FontConfig is not used on Mac, though. There you will need to make the fonts available to the system the usual Mac way (whatever it is, my Mac knowledge is very limited).

Comment: @KhaledHosny thanks I update the wording a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works! I had some problem because of MathJax installed some fonts that interfere with the standard ones and so fc-cache was confused. So I removed MJ and the installed it again after fc-chace. Otherwise I guess I should have done some manual workaround...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The solution code doesn't work for me, even though I have CMU Serif installed. I get the error `Font shape 'TU/CMUSerif(0)/b/sc' undefined using 'TU/CMUSerif(0)/b/n' instead on input line 13`. However it works fine when I use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: @simplejack your coments here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587223/how-to-get-cmu-small-caps-as-a-separate-font#comment1475415_587223 imply th efont is not installed?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Font Book says it is installed so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!!!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}    
\usepackage{libertine}    
%\usepackage{mathpazo}    
%\usepackage{newtxtext}    
%\usepackage{charter}    
%\usepackage{kpfonts}    
%\usepackage{fourier}    
%\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}    
%\usepackage{pxfonts}    
\begin{document}    
\bfseries\scshape Rhubarb Rhubarb    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using XeLaTeX, so I should pass thorugh `fontspec`