# XeLaTeX and fontspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, latin-modern

I'm askin a very simple question. I'm using XeLaTeX on Linux, and it's working perfectly. I know that Latin Modern Roman is the default font used by `\usepackage{fontspec}`. However I would like to know what is its name: I tried to use

```
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
```

but it tells me that it couldn't find such a font. Even in ShareLaTeX I have the same problem. This can be useful if I decide to switch font and then to return to Latin Modern? Which name should I use?

thanks

## EDIT

Performing `fc-match -a modern | grep -i "latin modern"` on the command shell I get

```
LatinModernMathJax_Alphabets-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Arrows-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_DoubleStruck-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Fraktur-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Latin-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Main-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Marks-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Misc-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Monospace-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_NonUnicode-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Normal-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Operators-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_SansSerif-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Script-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Shapes-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Size1-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Size2-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Size3-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Size4-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Size5-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Size6-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Size7-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Symbols-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
LatinModernMathJax_Variants-Regular.woff: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
```

it seems that all Latin Modern I have depend on MathJax, it's strange.

Comment: whether you can access a font by internal font name depends on where it is installed but for latin modern `\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont` should always work

Comment: Try `\setmainfont{LM Roman 10}` (or `12` if your base size is 12pt).

Comment: It doesn't work, while `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}` works with lualatex. How can I make it work also with xelatex?

Comment: What do you get at a prompt with `fc-match -a modern | grep -i "latin modern"`?

Comment: @ArashEsbati I've just edited my question

Comment: I see `lmroman10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "10 Regular"` (among others).  `xetex` relies on `fontconfig` to find fonts.  I presume you're using TeXlive.  Follow the instructions [in the docs](http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-340003.4.4) and see if that helps.

Comment: `.woff` fonts cannot be used by XeTeX, as far as I know

Comment: I found a directory in which there are my `.otf` files. But it seems that `\setmainfont' accept only the file name with xelatex. With lualatex it accepts also the font name. How can I make xelatex find the right font also by name?

Comment: Are your otf fonts in XeTeX's tree, or in the System fonts directory, or elsewhere? Unlike LuaTeX, XeTeX relies on the System's capabilities to find fonts by name, iiuc.

Comment: It should work if you install a fontconfig file as in your other CMU question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one has to write a file `70-prevent-MJ.conf` in `/etc/fonts/conf.d` with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
 <selectfont>
  <rejectfont><glob>/usr/share/fonts/mathjax/*</glob></rejectfont>
 </selectfont>
</fontconfig>
```

This prevent `fontconfig` to index MathJax font.