# How to get CMU small caps as a separate font?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, font-encodings, computer-modern

CMU bold small capitals work for me with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` but not with `\usepackage{fontspec}`. Is there a way to get a separate CMU font that *only* has small capitals? When I buy fonts they come with separate files for small capitals and that works fine with `fontspec`.

*Edit*

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman 10 Regular}[
    BoldFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = {CMU Serif Bold}},
    SmallCapsFont = Latin Modern Roman Caps]

\begin{document}

Roman. \textbf{Bold.} \textsc{Small capitals.} 
\textbf{\textsc{Bold small capitals.}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us how you load CMU at present using commands of the `fontspec` package.

Comment: @Mico Please see update. I am only trying to use bold small capitals from CMU. The output is bold but not small caps.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334406/87678 help?

Comment: (The CMU opentype fonts include small caps as an open type feature, not as a separate font, btw)

Comment: @DavidPurton I tried using the Terminal commands from the linked answer. The first one was executed but the second was not. `fc-cache command not found`. So at this point it still doesn't work.

Comment: @simplejack, what about the `\setmainfont{cmun}` option which searches by file name? (`fc-cache` is a Linux command, so presumably you aren't running Linux).

Comment: Oh, and the Computer Modern Unicode fonts are not the same as the Latin Modern fonts.

Comment: @DavidPurton `\setmainfont{cmun}` doesn't work. `font not found`

Comment: Im not sure exactly what you tried. You need the full set of options from the linked answer. Or Try *just* `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}` and remove all your other font commands except for `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Comment: I don't think Latin Modern includes bold small caps

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the features for small caps in a boldface context.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[
  BoldFeatures = {
    SmallCapsFont = CMU Serif Bold Extended Roman,
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
  },
  SmallCapsFont = Latin Modern Roman Caps,
]

\begin{document}

Roman. \textbf{Bold.} \textsc{Small capitals.}
\textbf{\textsc{Bold small capitals.}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Latin Modern Roman font does not include a bold small caps variant.

You can use the CMR Unicode font.

This should work with both `xelatex` and `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{fontspec}    
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}    
\begin{document}    
\scshape small caps \bfseries bold small caps    
\end{document}
```

[image: output]