# what is the search order of latex font under linux

Tags: fonts, xetex

Today when I compile the latex project using xelatex with texlive 2023, it tell me the fonts xxxx did not found. So I was wonder what is the fonts default search order of latex in linux system? which location will the xelatex will search? is the system font was last one to search?

Comment: Note that xetex is know to be very fuzzy about where it looks for fonts. Luatex is much more forgiven.

Comment: xelatex uses different search algorithms depending on how you ask. If you give a filename such as `foobar-regular.otf` it uses kpathsearch as for tex files (and will find system files and files in texlive)  if you give an internal font name like `TeX Gyre Termes` it uses fontconfig and won't find texlive files unless you have added the texlive font directories to your fontconfig configuration

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344087/1090